# Order of operations in plot(\x, {function})

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I draw a random function with `plot (\x, {function})`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick,scale=1,domain=-0.83:10,samples=100,smooth,variable=\x] plot(\x,{(1/((\x)+1))-cos((180/pi)*0.2*(\x)^2)*0.5*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output looks nice, however I don't think that this is the function given in the expression because if I give the same function to Wolframalpha, it looks very different. I know for example that one must write `(\x)^2` instead of `\x^2` in `plot` to get the square function. Is there other similar rules that I am missing? Or maybe I did not copy the function correctly into Wolframalpha but I am quite sure I did. I put all possible parenthesis in the expression to make sure that the order of operations was right but it is still different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `\x` has to be converted to degrees inside the cosine function using `deg(\x)` instead of `\x`. Another option is to work with radians using the option `\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad}` when you use pgfplots.

Here is my attempt using pgfplots:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  
\begin{axis}
[
    ymin=-0.5,ymax=4.2,xmin=-0.85,xmax=1.05,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line shift=-0.5,
    axis y line shift=-0.85,
    minor tick num = 2,
    ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
    ticklabel style = {fill=white,inner sep =2pt},
    width = 10cm,
    height = 7cm,
    grid=both,
    major grid style = {lightgray!50},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!40,dotted},
]
\addplot[thick,blue,domain=-0.7:0.96,samples=1000] {(1/(\x+1))-cos((180/pi)*0.2*(\x)^2)*0.5*\x};       
\end{axis}
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

close to the Wolframalpha results:
[image]

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! So for the other way around, I just had to get rid of the (180/pi) in Wolframalpha :)

Comment: Correct, you're welcome :)